# Bullet point list inside of a table

Tags: tables, lists, itemize

```
\noindent \begin{tabular}{@{} l l}

 \Large{Education}    & \textbf{University} \\
     & Degree, Major, May 2018. \\
\begin{itemize}
  \item Course 1
  \item Course 2
  \item blah, blah.
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
```

I'm trying to insert a bullet point list inside of my table, however the output looks something like this.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your example should not even compile since `itemize` can't be used inside an `l` - columntype (at least not this way!). Replace the first `l` with `p{2in}`, i.e. making a parbox - column of width `2in`. You can choose another width of course

Comment: it looks to me as if you're writing your resumeé. why don't you use either `cv` or `moderncv`-class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply add bullet points in you LaTex tables, there is a sample which I hope it helps:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{.03\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|}
%%%
\begin{itemize}
  \item Sample Text
  \item Sample Text
  \end{itemize}
  & Hi &
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Sample Text
  \item Sample Text
\end{itemize}\\
%%%
\begin{itemize}
  \item Sample Text
  \item Sample Text
  \end{itemize}
  & Hi &
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Sample Text
  \item Sample Text
\end{itemize}
%%%

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The output would be like:
[image]
Also in your code, you need to drop the `l` and work with `p`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tabular}{|p{0.6\textwidth}|p{0.6\textwidth}|}

 \Large{Education}    & \textbf{University} \\
     & Degree, Major, May 2018. \\
\begin{itemize}
  \item Course 1
  \item Course 2
  \item blah, blah.
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why in the itemized fields there is always a skipped line?