# Shrinking a cell including citation and using bullet points in tables

Tags: tables

I have the following table and I want to modify two things:

1) Shrink the first column by possibly using two or more lines for the citation
2) Using bullet points for the last column content.

```
\begin{table*}[th!]
  \center
  \scriptsize
  \caption{Systematic literature review.\label{tab:lit_rev}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lllllX}
    Article & Methodology & Model objective & Decision phase & Vehicle Types & Features\\
    \hline
    \cite{ma2017designing} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Linear\\ programming\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Minimize traffic\\ on arcs\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Operational,\\ rolling horizon\end{tabular} & SAV           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No carpooling\\ Parking at any node\\ Simulated traffic congestion\\ Flexible departure times\end{tabular} \\
    \hline
    \cite{hyland2018dynamic} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Agent-based\\ simulation\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Minimize miles\\ driven and\\ client wait times\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Operational,\\ rolling horizon,\\ real-time\end{tabular} & SAV & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}No carpooling\\ No info on parking\\ No traffic congestion\\ Flexible pick up time\\ Fixed number of AVs per day\end{tabular} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

Below is a screenshot to see how it currently looks like. For my modification 1, I couldn't find a proper way. If I used a numbered in-text citation, I would not have such an issue but it is not an option. For the second one, I found some useful links such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150492/how-to-use-itemize-in-table-environment) and [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329008/bullet-point-list-inside-of-a-table/329023) but they require using tabular instead of tabularx.

[image]

Comment: You can try a p type column for the first column.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I tried this: {p{0.09\linewidth}llllX}. It works but introduces new problems. Citations start after a single line space and some lines include first and last name abbreviations in a very weird way like (K.           M.)

Comment: Could you please ake your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages and also two example citations? (See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/134144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion based on assumptions and gesses about the documentclass and citations used. I have used a left aligned `p` type column for the first column as well as for the last column. To get the bullet points in the last column, I have defined a new environment `tabitem` with the help of the `enumitem` package. Lastly, I have removed teh nested tabulars in columns 2-4 and used left aligned `X` txpe columns for them. 
As you can see from the following screenshots and example, you could even increase teh font size from `\scriptsize` fo `\footnotesize` of even `\small` and still fit the table nicely into the textwidth. If your table should becoome too long for a single page, you might want to have a look at the `xltabular` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= * ,label=\textbullet,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ma2017designing,
  author = {Ma, A.},
  year = {2007},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{hyland2018dynamic,
  author = {Hyland, A. and Mahmassani},
  year = {2018},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[th!]
  \center
  \scriptsize
  \caption{Systematic literature review.\label{tab:lit_rev}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}lp{4cm}}
    Article & Methodology & Model\newline objective & Decision phase & Vehicle Types & Features\\
    \toprule
    \cite{ma2017designing} & Linear programming & Minimize traffic on arcs & Operational, rolling horizon & SAV           & \begin{tabitem} \item No carpooling \item Parking at any node \item Simulated traffic congestion \item Flexible departure times\end{tabitem} \\
    \midrule
    \cite{hyland2018dynamic} & Agent-based simulation & Minimize miles driven and client wait times & Operational, rolling horizon, real-time & SAV & \begin{tabitem}\item No carpooling \item No info on parking \item No traffic congestion \item Flexible pick up time \item Fixed number of AVs per day\end{tabitem} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}[th!]
  \center
  \footnotesize
  \caption{Systematic literature review.\label{tab:lit_rev}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}lp{4.2cm}}
    Article & Methodology & Model\newline objective & Decision phase & Vehicle Types & Features\\
    \toprule
    \cite{ma2017designing} & Linear programming & Minimize traffic on arcs & Operational, rolling horizon & SAV           & \begin{tabitem} \item No carpooling \item Parking at any node \item Simulated traffic congestion \item Flexible departure times\end{tabitem} \\
    \midrule
    \cite{hyland2018dynamic} & Agent-based simulation & Minimize miles driven and client wait times & Operational, rolling horizon, real-time & SAV & \begin{tabitem}\item No carpooling \item No info on parking \item No traffic congestion \item Flexible pick up time \item Fixed number of AVs per day\end{tabitem} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}[th!]
  \center
  \small \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
  \caption{Systematic literature review.\label{tab:lit_rev}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}lp{4.4cm}}
    Article & Methodology & Model\newline objective & Decision phase & Vehicle Types & Features\\
    \toprule
    \cite{ma2017designing} & Linear programming & Minimize traffic on arcs & Operational, rolling horizon & SAV           & \begin{tabitem} \item No carpooling \item Parking at any node \item Simulated traffic congestion \item Flexible departure times\end{tabitem} \\
    \midrule
    \cite{hyland2018dynamic} & Agent-based simulation & Minimize miles driven and client wait times & Operational, rolling horizon, real-time & SAV & \begin{tabitem}\item No carpooling \item No info on parking \item No traffic congestion \item Flexible pick up time \item Fixed number of AVs per day\end{tabitem} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are great! Thank you very much for allotting time.